# Java and sockets, the code doesn´t continue

Tags: java, client-server

I am not an expert in this, but the code code below just prints message "Waiting for connection.....", and doesn´t print other messages. Why? There is no exception and the thread is running, but after calling accept() method, it doesn´t continue.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

            try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(0);//0 any free port
            } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: xxx.");
            System.exit(1);
            }

            Socket clientSocket = null;
            System.out.println("Waiting for connection.....");

            //  try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            /*  } catch (IOException e) {
             System.err.println("Accept failed.");
             System.exit(1);
             }*/
             //And now there is no output, "Waiting for connection....." is the last one
            System.out.println("Connection successful");
            System.out.println("Waiting for input.....");

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Server: " + inputLine);
            out.println(inputLine);

            if (inputLine.equals("Bye.")) {
                break;
            }
            }

            out.close();
            in.close();
            clientSocket.close();
            serverSocket.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Sockets.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        }
```

Comment: How do you know which port it listens on in order to send it some data?

Comment: Did you write any thing after opening a socket to server ? Where is the client code which create Socket clientSocket = new Socket(ip,port)? After creating clinetSocket, open output stream and write something, Then Server can get it in InputStream

Comment: Have a look at my post @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32486607/java-socket-remote-desktop-connection/32487098#32487098 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32548614/server-doesnt-receive-message-in-client-server-application/32548893#32548893

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code works for me, provided I updated the code to tell me port to connect my client to. Try changing the waiting message to:

```
System.out.println("Waiting for connection on port " + serverSocket.getLocalPort() + ".....");
```

and then connecting to that port using telnet:

```
telnet localhost <port number>
```

I got it echoing my input back just fine.

You could pass in the desired port as a command line parameter, rather than simply picking an arbitrary one.